# Auto refresh 2 iframes on different time interval

Tags: html, iframe, refresh

I have 2 Iframes on my page which showing 2 different pages. I just wanted to refresh them automatically on different time intervals(first page each 60Sec and Second one each 300Sec). Please suggest me some simple and best solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi!
Have you tried anything yet?
I think that you could solve your problem with some JavaScript that runs at a set interval to trigger reloading of said iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript like this:

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame1();", 60000);
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame2();", 300000);

function reloadIFrame1() {
 document.frames["frameNameHere1"].location.reload();
}
function reloadIFrame2() {
 document.frames["frameNameHere2"].location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Malik, where should i suppose to place this script? on or bottom of the page?

Comment: You can add it on bottom of the page before `body` tag ends.

Comment: and the time should be on mile-seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
<script>
window.setInterval("refreshIFrame1();", 60000);

function refreshIFrame1() {
 document.getElementById('FrameID1').location.reload();
}

window.setInterval("refreshIFrame2();", 300000);
function refreshIFrame2() {
 document.getElementById('FrameID2').location.reload();
}
</script>
```